# Check if www.listentoyoutube.com provides exact audio copy

Tags: mp3, sound-quality, youtube

If this question do not belong to this site, please tell me where it belongs if you are kind.
I need to download the exact sound clip of youtube videos, and I've been using this online site: www.listentoyoutube.com. When entering a youtube video url, after following trivial steps one downloads a mp3 file with supposedly the audio part of the video, in mp3 format. I want to know if this audio part matches exactly that of the youtube video.
I'm aware that the video and audio of youtube are separated, so my question makes sense.
My concern is that the website extracts the audio and probably converts it so that it looses quality.

Answer (score 1):

### What you can do

- Download your video from this website with (lossless) settings and desired quality:

  [cconverter](http://www.clipconverter.cc)
- make a checksum of both audio files

  The one downloaded by **listentoyoutube** and the one by **cconverter**.

  After converting them to a lossless audio file format (using ffmpeg for example) compare them with the checksum command line on your terminal.

  The following post might help you:

  [related post](https://superuser.com/questions/531778/how-to-compare-two-lossless-audio-files)

Cheers,

Comment: Two questions. First, by downloading a video with lossless settings, I have only to do these steps: paste the link in the text box, and then press "download" (wich says no conversion in the hidden caption) , and then press continue? And then start, wait for the conversion... then download. That's what you are telling me to do? I think I understand. But this involves downloading probably much more data in some cases.

Comment: yes you've understood well. Only thing is that I'm telling you to dl this time the video in order to compare if your website does the job you're waiting for. If everything sounds good then no need to go through cconverter anymore.